# 2-Way Binding a Property of a Component in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to make a directive, where one set of Input/Output fields are linked to be like a 2 way binding as per with [(ngModel)].

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
@Component({
    selector: "template-for-inputbox",
    template: 
    `
     <div><label>{{Label}}</label>
         <input [(ngModel)]="Value"/>
     </div>
    `
})
export class TemplateForInputBoxDirective{
    @Input() DataValue:any;
    @Output() DataChanged:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    get Value(){
        return this.Data;
    }
    set Value(tValue){
         //Check some things about the new value then...
         this.DataChanged.emit(tValue);
    }
}
```

While reading http://victorsavkin.com/post/119943127151/angular-2-template-syntax I tried creating a directive to split things out:

```
@Directive({
    selector: "[Data]",
    host: {
        "[DataValue]": "Data",
        "(DataChanged)":"DataChanging.next($event)"
    }
})
export class DataBinding {
    @Input() Data: any;
    @Output() DataChanging: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    ngOnInit() {
        let vData = this.Data;
    }
}
```

Where I would then use it like this:

```
<template-for-inputbox [(Data)]="SomeObject.Value"></template-for-inputbox>
```

As opposed to:

```
<template-for-inputbox [DataValue]="SomeObject.Value"
                       (DataChanged)="SomeObject.Value = $event">
</template-for-inputbox>
```

The objects and number of times this comes up makes the bottom version just a mess.

But so far only the bottom version is working, the values I'm dealing with in the top version don't do anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to do two way binding, the output variable name should be, `inputVarName + 'Change'`. So, in your example, it will be `DataChange` and the input variable `Data`.

```
export class TemplateForInputBoxDirective{
    @Input() Data:any;
    @Output() DataChange:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    get Value(){
        return this.Data;
    }
    set Value(tValue){
         //Check some things about the new value then...
         this.DataChange.emit(tValue);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
<template-for-inputbox [(Data)]="SomeObject.Value"></template-for-inputbox>
```

**Just a note**, the convention is to use PascalCase for class names and camelCase for variable names. It's so confusing to read the variables PascalCased

Comment: is it necessary to write `inputVarName + 'Change'` for two way binding  ?

Comment: @PardeepJain yes, in order to use it like `[(inputVarName)]` the name of the variable with `@Output()` decorator has to match the one decorated `@Input()` with the word `Change` appended. Of course, you can set the name inside the decorator instead of the variable name like `@Output('inputVarNameChange')`